# Custom UITableViewCell is missing the line separator

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have set a UITableView's line separator style and colour in IB, however, when the table loads the separator lines are not visible.

I am using a UITableView which has a custom superclass `CustomTableView` - this is a subclass of `UITableView`. In this table, I am also using a custom `UITableViewCell`.

The only issue I could think it would be is if I didn't call the 'super' implementation in my `awakeFromNib` method - but I do this so it can't be that.

Any ideas?

**EDIT with code**

My table cell is as follows - CustomDefaultCell.h > CustomPlainCell.h > UITableViewCell

CustomDefaultCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Called when loaded from a nib.
    // Override all default cell behaviour here.
    //
}
```

CustomPlainCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Called when loaded from a nib.
    // Override all default cell behaviour here.
    //
    // Normal background view
    self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Selected background view
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    //
    // Background gradient
    CAGradientLayer *selectedViewGradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    selectedViewGradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) + 1.0f);
    selectedViewGradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithHue:0.0f saturation:0.0f brightness:0.57f alpha:1.0f].CGColor, (id)[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];

    [self.selectedBackgroundView.layer addSublayer:selectedViewGradientLayer];
}
```

Comment: Are you using Quartz to draw your content?

Comment: I have a .xib file, with corresponding .h and .m

Comment: I know, but what's in the .h and m.? (Don't tell me "there's code inside"!)

Comment: Sorry, just realised whata silly answer that was :P Edited with code

Comment: oh yes, just as I thought! You **are** using Quartz to draw your cell's content. The solution: move all the setSelected method's code into drawRect:.

Comment: I have moved the code into `drawRect:` and deleted the `setSelected:animated:` method - however, the separator's still aren't being drawn

Comment: I am also calling the super method (of drawRect:) too

Comment: as a workaround, you can draw an 1px border around your cell in the end of the drawing procedure.

Comment: Is there a method which doesn't involve a work around? It seems messy/buggy to do otherwise

Comment: try `selectedViewGradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 1.0f);` (notice the minus instead of the plus).

Comment: Still nothing - ive even tried removing the background gradient code as well as using the viewDidLoad method to set the table separator properties - which isn't any good.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, when i find the solution i will add it here!

Comment: It seems the code in my awakeFromNib method above overrides the border (the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView)

Comment: intersting (well, rather annoying). One more reason why I don't like Interface Builder :)

Comment: What would be the best way to add a subview to the cell in `CustomPlainCell.h` only if it is not the last cell in the section - I have tried adding a property to it (BOOL isLastCell) but cells get reused rather than alloc/init :/

Comment: you can always add subviews to a cell's `contentView` property. Just make sure they're smaller (less high) than the cell itself.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and figured that I was not calling `[super layoutSubviews];` when overriding that method in cell prototype class.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I decided yo use the delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and if the cell was a subclass of 'CustomPlainCell', add a 1pt high `UIView` with a background colour.